# Why is there no filter in triage review?

Tags: support, triage

Is there any specific reason why we do not have a filter in the "Triage" section of the review queues? There are tag filters for the "First Posts" and "Late Answers" queues, so doesn't it make sense to have filters for "Triage" also?

Comment: It's no filter, but, I wrote a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6771/review-tag-repositioner) that repositions the tags when working in the review queue.

Comment: That question is a feature request without answer. *This* question asks why. Not a duplicate.

Comment: Less dramatic than a filter: moving the tags above the question so they're easy to see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376869/in-triage-move-tags-above-the-question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Triage reviewing requires less domain specific knowledge than other types of reviews. It's a first pass at questions, to catch things that are obviously in violation of some basic posting policies, or identifying things that are hard to understand, regardless of the technology being used.

Also, it's easy for posts that need triage to be tagged incorrectly. If users filtered them, these posts might never be reviewed. For example, spammers could pick tags that are never used (and thus, would unlikely be included in anyone's filter), and those spams posts could linger.

Comment: Less domain specific knowledge, but still so much that I press skip a lot. What about doing it in a two-step fashion? Something like a button: "looks ok, but needs a domain expert" ?

Comment: Less domain specific knowledge, but need be checked triage was tagged correctly.

Comment: well, at least language tags like [python] should be allowed as filters, I have no way to assess if stuff requires editing in languages I am unfamiliar with. It discourages me to start triaging or first post reviewing when things are left the way they are.

Comment: considering the fact that tags are automatically suggested, these could be used regardless of manually added tags that might be wrong